Is ICAP standard alive?
ICAP: Inter exchange Client Address Protocol
aka Ethereum IBAN.
Are there wallets that support ICAP?
Example:
ICAP: XE472EVKU3CGMJF2YQ0J9RO1Y90BC0LDFZ


It is not alive, and was not adopted in the first place.
ICAP is just a margin note in the history of Ethereum.
